# Can I have a Mongoose document delete itself from an instance method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, instance-methods

Title explains it all. I have a Mongoose document that has an instance method like this:

```
Model.methods.destroy = function(callback) {
    // blah blah
    this.remove(callback);
}
```

How can I tell an instance of `Model` to delete itself? When I try `this.remove`, it tells me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'remove'
```

and `this.constructor` does not have a `remove` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. It can be done. I wasn't handling asynchronicity properly. I saved an instance of `this` in a `var self` earlier and I was trying `this.remove` instead of `self.remove`.